# how to fetch rows from mysql to table header and specific data related with that fetched header

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables `question_details` and `paid_response`

`question_details` contains

```
 qno  qshortcode
 504   what do you want
 515   what is your name
 541   what is your address
  .
  .
 other..  others question
```

`paid_response` contains

```
 qno   paid_respo   paid_rev    sys_date
 504    yes         0.60       2014-12-16 04:14:40
 515    no          0.42       2014-12-17 04:14:40
```

now i want `qshortcode` from `question_details` with given `qno(504 and 515)` and paid_respo from `paid_response` table where paid_rev not=0.00 and between two dates

```
what do you want    what is your name   //fetching from `question_details` table
yes                  no                 //fetching from `paid_response` table with respect to `qno` where paid_rev not 0.00
```

my code for fetching `qshortcode from`question_details` table

```
<?php
//DB connection goes here

$query=mysql_query("select qshortcode from question_details where qno=504 or qno='515'");   
echo '<tr>';
for($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);$i++) {
echo '<td>'.$row['qshortcode'].'</td>';           
echo '</tr>';                        
} ?>
```

its fetching like

```
what do you want what is your name

 //cant fetch paid_respo of specific qshortcode below this where paid_rev not euqals to 0.00 or blank
```

Comment: You need to look into `JOIN`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:use **join** to **combine** both the tables

```
<?php
//DB connection goes here

$query=mysql_query("select qshortcode,paid_respo from question_details left join paid_response on paid_response.qno=question_details.qno  where question_details.qno in (504,515)");   


     echo '<table>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr>';//to show each response as one row.
        echo '<td>'.$row['qshortcode'].'</td>';//what do you want
        echo '<td>'.$row['paid_respo'].'</td>';//yes            
        echo '</tr>';                        
        } 
    echo '</table>'

?>
```

Comment: its coming in a single line

Comment: you have to add table tag before while loop.